# Windows 8.1 Universal App exception stack trace is too short (even in DEBUG)

Tags: c#, exception, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I wrote windows 8.1 universal app (monogame/Windows8.1) in Visual Studio 2013 and try to catch stack trace of exception in draw thread. I added handlers to

- CoreApplication.UnhandledErrorDetected
- Application.Current.UnhandledException
- TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException
- AsyncSynchronizationContext.Register()

In project settings I set full debug info.
Now I have 2 problems: I get only one line of my call (and async garbage like MoveTo and Result()) and this line even doesn't have line numbers:

HRESULT: -2147024864
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   **at com.mytest.CBackground.d__0.MoveNext()**

Stack above I get when throw exception in async method.  If I throw exception in non-async method handler of Application gets full stack trace, but again without line numbers.

However if I write:

```
        try
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            s = e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace;
        }
```

I get only one line - name of method where I threw that exception. Why?

1. How can I get line numbers?
2. Why there are no previous lines (calls from my code to my method com.mytest.CBackground.setupBootActions())?

Even if I launch with debugging from VS there is no line numbers when I break on exception.

Comment: Hmya, this is something you are going to have to get used to when you target UWP.  You get no line numbers because none of your code is involved with this mishap.  The price of async/await, this is the async callback that ran because of the I/O completion and it failed with a very plain error code.  -2147024864 == 0x80070020 == winapi error 32 == "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process".   Use Debug > Windows > Threads to find the thread with the await call, it has a stack trace.  Just assume that opening a file can always fail.

Comment: 1. the funniest thing this stack is produced by await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync(). So if there are any files - it is internally. 2. Yes, with async I get the idea, BUT I'M NOT GETTING LINE NUMBERS WITH NON-ASYNC CODE EITHER!